# how to add next and prev button to element with the inline property

Tags: fancybox

I am trying to create a web-based ## e-exam app ## . Rather than having about 40 questions displayed at time,I want the questions to be displayed one at a time,then use navigation button to navigate through and fro.  Tried using the `class="fancybox-buttons`"  in each div tag  containing each question, but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Just create a hidden field for each question with the question's URI as a value.  Have that read by a JS function invoked by an onclick() event. Name the html pages by the question number, e.g., 1.html, 2.html, etc.

For the first question, insert:

```
<input type='hidden' value='1' id='question'/>
```

For the nav buttons,

```
<input type='button' value='Prev' onclick="getPrevious(document.getElementById('question');"/>
<input type='button' value='Next' onclick="getNext(document.getElementById('question');"/>
```

For the JS:

```
<script>
function getPrevious(question) {
    if( question.value == 1 ) {
        return;

    } else {
        window.location = (question.value - 1) + ".html";
    }
}

function getNext(question) {
    if( question.value == 40 ) {
        return;

    } else {
        window.location = (question.value + 1) + ".html";
    }
}
</script>
```